# Set Transient on CPT

Tags: wp-query, loop, transient

When I add set_transient code to my cpt query, I get a `Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on string ... on line 30`

Line 30 is basically: `if($graduate_student_query->have_posts()) : ?>`

Without the set_transient the query works just fine, but it's obviously not best practices. Where should the set_transient go?

```
<?php 
        if ( false === ( $graduate_student_query = get_transient( 'graduate_student_query' ) ) ) {
            $graduate_student_query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'people',
                'role' => 'leadership',
                'meta_key' => 'ecpt_people_alpha',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => '-1'));         
    set_transient( 'graduate_student_query', $graduate_student_query, 2592000 );
} 
 if($graduate_student_query->have_posts()) : ?>
 {some HTML code}
  <?php while ($graduate_student_query->have_posts()) : $graduate_student_query->the_post(); ?>
```

Do I need to establish the set_transient outside of this loop, at the top of the template document?

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump()` `$graduate_student_query` before the `if()` clause?

Comment: `var_dump($graduate_student_query);` immediately before renders: `string(0)""`

Comment: Ok. Next, set `delete_transient('graduate_student_query');` right at the top of your snippet. Then `var_dump()` `$graduate_student_query` right after you set it. That'll make sure your WP_Query is working. (You also may just have accidentally set some junk value for the transient once.) This can be handy too: https://wordpress.org/plugins/transients-manager/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting a full blown answer now that we've figured it out.

---

Transients can be hard to troubleshoot because if you save the wrong value to the database at first, you can be looking at an old—and bad—value, even if the code that sets your transient is now correct.

The two ways you can fix this are to temporarily use [`delete_transient()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_transient) or use a [plugin like Transients Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/transients-manager/). The plugin has the advantage of showing you the value of transients as well which can speed up troubleshooting.

In the example above, the simplest way is just to start the snippet like this:

```
<?php
delete_transient('graduate_student_query'); // this is the magic
if ( false === ( $graduate_student_query = get_transient( 'graduate_student_query' ) ) ) {
    // etc...
```

That means the old value gets cleared, the full code runs, the transient is resaved, and you get to see if you used the correct value now.

Then **be sure to remove `delete_transient()`** from the code. Otherwise, you're deleting it and regenerating it every time and your code is even more inefficient than it was before!